# github codespaces & docker-compose, how to mount a (secrets) file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-codespaces

I've create a vscode devcontainer. For this I configured a `docker-compose.yaml` file where one of the services has this:

```
    volumes:
      - c:/docker/license/oe-12.8/progress.cfg:/usr/dlc/progress.cfg
```

Now this works locally, but my question is how to mimic this when using github codespaces? I can't commit the `progress.cfg` file since it contains a license which I do not want to share (it's a secret basically).

Any help is appreciated.

Edit: `progress.cfg` is a binary file.